# Where rails view finds these methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, actionview

Iam working with Rails from nearly 1 year and as a learner the most difficult matter to me is the view stuff.

I have view file that embeds this: `<%= index %>`. I tried to find where this method is defined in the code. I searched and found 12 definitions for `index` but non of them was in a helper. I googled it (sometimes strange names like `options_from_collection_for_select` OMG :<> appear to be part of the ActionView library) i didnt find it in the action view stuff either.

So I have had this problem multiple times and couldn't find out how the view automagically find this method.

Could you please guide me where to search?

Comment: could you please provide the complete block of view instead of just one word.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the ruby method `source_location` to know where a method is defined.

But you need to execute it in a context where you have access to it. So, if it's helper, then you can, in a `rails console`, try something like `helper.method(:index).source_location`

If it's not a helper (as it doesn't seem to be), then try to add a breaking point for example, and run `method(:index).source_location`, you should be able to locate it

But, are you sure that it's not a local variable, given when calling a partial, or from a `each_with_index` block ? It's really strange to name a method index without more context :/

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to know where and how a method is defined is to use [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug)'s `binding.pry`.

You can put `<% binding.pry %>` in your view file, reload the page, and then see the source of the desired method by entering `show-source method_name` in the command prompt that has appeared in your Rails server output. (`show-source index` in your case.)